# Выложить git репозиторий в локальную сеть

Tags: git, windows-10, smartgit

У меня появился сетевой диск, и его я хочу использовать для храния git репозиториев. На компе у меня есть проект, который я давно веду. Теперь хочу его выложить на сетевой диск `Z:\`.

Если есть возможность сделать через программу SmartGit, хорошо. Если нет, то через консоль консоль.

ОС: Windows 10, git version 2.12.0.windows.1, SmartGit 18.1.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно просто клонировать репозиторий в нужное расположение

```
Z:
cd Z:\
git clone C:\путь_к_папкe_с_вашим_проектом\ --bare
```

Через ГУИ вам нужно встать в папку куда будете клонировать, вызвать команду clone\клонировать, указать опцию bare\голый, ввести расположение исходного репозитория.

Опция `--bare` позволит пользоваться репозиторием как удаленным, то есть в него можно будет отправлять фиксации, вытягивать и т.д. Но нельзя будет пользоваться как локальным, т.к. в нём не будет индексированных файлов в чистом виде - только в служебном.

Если нужно, чтобы файлы в чистом виде были доступны --- не используйте опцию `--bare`