# Как клонировать репозиторий git с одного компьютера на другой по локальной сети

Tags: windows, git, cmd, контроль-версий

OS Windows, нужно клонировать репозиторий с компьютера на другой компьютер, они оба в локальной сети ну и кидать обновления в будущем на другой компьютер.

Пробовал команду с компьютера на который нужно клонировать: `git clone //19.170.1.91/C$/PROG/SERVER`

В ответ мне пишет: fatal: `repository //19.170.1.91/C$/PROG/SERVER does not exist`

Пробовал вместо ip писать имя компьютера, пробовал с file:// писать, не выходит ничего.
До этого каким-то образом работник до меня использовал pull и fetch но на другом железе, при этом в командах использовал только имена компьютеров без указания путей кроме определения пути в начале.

Оба компьютера пингуются, сеть работает.

---

Может ли это быть связано с сетевыми ограничениями?

Comment: так этот путь просто в проводнике открывается?

Comment: по указанному пути, вероятно, находится не хранилище (aka репозиторий), а всего лишь рабочий каталог этого хранилища. само же хранилище явно чуть глубже — в под-каталоге `.git`. но клонировать не-bare хранилище — это плохой подход.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать удаленный репозиторий git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727814/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-git)

Comment: дубликаты, дополняющие суть: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/735635/178576) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918926/178576) и т.п. из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+is%3Aa+bare

Comment: Нужен `git-server`, это вам не `peer-to-peer`, а для этого его нужно настроить: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: @megorit, совершенно не обязательно наличие каких-нибудь там «git-server-ов». общее bare-хранилище — это же всего лишь набор файлов. не надо никаких git-специфичных надстроек, чтобы эти файлы использовать с разных компьютеров в одной сети.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Очень интересно, как тогда еще можно?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , а как это можно реализовать? Я вообще не понимаю в каком месте ошибаюсь так как нет описания ошибки, только что не существует такого репозитория

Comment: @Decay, как минимум, к папке с репозиторием должен быть открыт доступ через локальную сеть - через свойства этой папки. Тогда она станет доступна по сети как `19.170.1.91/SERVER`. Дальше на целевом компьютере ее подключаете, должны стать видны файлы в ней. Потом из нее клонируете.

Comment: @Decay, ну я же указал в комментариях подходящие вопросы. совсем кратко: вам надо создать bare-хранилище в каком-нибудь пустом каталоге, расшарить файловый доступ по сети к этому каталогу, отправить туда историю из текущего хранилища (сделать «push»), а затем клонировать с любого из компьютеров в локальной сети. вы же умеете в локальной сети расшаривать каталоги с возможностью записи в них?

Comment: @insolor , спасибо, на старом сервере был доступ дан, повторил настройки. К сожалению проблему саму не решило.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , в таком случае копируется только папка .git, а не весь проект :( 100% должен быть способ как клонировать репозиторий целиком на другое устройство для дальнейшей работы

Comment: @Decay, каталог `.git` и содержит хранилище. целиком и полностью. когда вы клонируете хранилище, по умолчанию в текущем каталоге разворачивается и его рабочий каталог. его содержимое извлекается из хранилища.

Comment: @Decay, вот вам немного ms/windows-специфики в указании путей к каталогу: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519933/4827341 (я от этой специфики страшно далёк уже лет двадцать как).

Comment: Попробовал всё перечисленное, все равно не выходит :(

Comment: `robocopy`? Или тебе прям средствами гита надо?

Comment: @donRumata , мне нужно скопировать папку со всеми изменениями для проверки их на сервере(файлы могут запортиться от резкого выключения и т.д.) ну и чтоб  я мог с компьютера коммиты посылать. Смотрю в сторону гит сервера уже, потому что других вариантов не вижу.

Comment: Ну если тупо копирование между виндо-компами, то робокопи отлично подойдёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось реализовать задуманное, так же в комментариях указали об этом решении.
Нужно было учесть все заглавные буквы в пути и авторизоваться с обоих устройств перейдя с одного на другое по нужному пути репозитория.
Таким образом можно клонировать репозиторий на другое устройство в локальной сети как на расшаренный диск и работать с нескольких устройств.

Comment: Промежуточные сервисы не нужны. Достаточно держать сервер на одной из машин - чтобы было куда подключаться с другой. Как вариант, расширить папку с репозиторием по сети и пушать с другого компьютера в общую папку. В этом случае в качестве сервера будет выступать файловый сервер.

Comment: @user7860670 , да у меня сейчас получилось подключиться таким образом но были нюансы от которых это не удавалось сделать

Comment: @user7860670, а  целостность БД это не может повредить, при одновременном изменении?

Comment: @PavelGridin Не должно. Гит вроде при работе с папкой создает .lock файл для синхронизации.